# decimales no se guardan c# y mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-forms

Al intentar guardar los datos si pongo por ejemplo: en el textbox un número como 10.37 en la base de datos solo aparece 10.00

```
       MySqlCommand mySqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("agregar_costo", Conexion.abrirConexion());
            mySqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pDes", txtMaterial.Text.Trim());
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pCost", Convert.ToDecimal(txtCostoUnitario.Text));
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pCat", "Material");        
            mySqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

lo tengo configurado para 2 decimales

Comment: de tipo decimal longitud 10

Comment: si, si lo hago directo de la bd funciona bien.. Solo en aplicación no

Comment: Has probado en cambiar el punto('.') por una coma (',') e intentar a ver si se introduce correctamente en la BD? Puede que el problema sea del huso horario que tengas configurado en tu BD, que te interpreta los puntos como separador de miles y no de decimales

Comment: se guarda todo como decir 2,34 y aparece 234